# Prevent onblur on input box after selecting value from Google places Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3

I want to prevent focus from shifting from an input field when user uses a mouse to select a suggestion for city/state provided by Google's places API.  This way, when user clicks Tab, focus can correctly shift to the next obvious input field.  But I'm unable to prevent an onblur event from occurring when user selects (using a mouse) a value proposed by Google's Autocomplete feature in its places API.  This issue doesn't happen when selecting a value using the keyboard.  Here's my code - appreciate some help in resolving this since I'm not very familiar with manipulation of Google's API code.

Here's my HTML code:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input gp-gac="{ types: ['(cities)'],  componentRestrictions: { country: 'US' }}" class="form-control"
      ng-model="home_ctrl.location"
      gp-components="{ locality: 'long_name', administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name' }"
      gp-callback="home_ctrl.gpSearchCb(result, place)"
      vs-city="home_ctrl.city"
      vs-state="home_ctrl.state"
      placeholder="City, State"
      id="txtCity">
  </div>
</div>
```

And here's the javascript code that calls on the Google places API:

```
(function() {
  'use strict'

  var gpGac = function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: '?ngModel',
      scope: {
        gpGac: '=',
        gpOptions: '=?',
        gpComponents: '=?',
        gpCity: '=?',
        gpState: '=?',
        gpZip: '=?',
        gpCallback: '&?',
      },
      link: {
        pre: function(scope, element, attributes, modelCtrl) {
          var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
              element[0],
              scope.gpGac,
            ),
            options = scope.gpOptions || {submitOnEnter: true},
            itemSelected

          scope.gpComponents = scope.gpComponents || {
            locality: 'long_name',
            sublocality: 'long_name',
            administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
            neighborhood: 'long_name',
            postal_code: 'short_name',
          }
          console.log(
            'scope.gpComponents: ' + JSON.stringify(scope.gpComponents),
          )
          var autocompleteListener = autocomplete.addListener(
            'place_changed',
            function() {
              var place = this.getPlace(),
                result = {}

              if (place.address_components) {
                place.address_components.forEach(function(addrComp) {
                  addrComp.types.forEach(function(type) {
                    if (scope.gpComponents && scope.gpComponents[type]) {
                      result[type] = addrComp[scope.gpComponents[type]]
                    }
                  })
                })

                scope.gpState = result.administrative_area_level_1
                if (result.locality && isOnDisplay(result.locality)) {
                  scope.gpCity = result.city = result.locality
                }
                if (result.sublocality && isOnDisplay(result.sublocality)) {
                  scope.gpCity = result.city = result.sublocality
                }
                if (result.neighborhood && isOnDisplay(result.neighborhood)) {
                  scope.gpCity = result.city = result.neighborhood
                }
                scope.gpZip = result.postal_code

                // check if it's displayed on input
                function isOnDisplay(addrComp) {
                  return place.formatted_address.search(addrComp) > -1
                }

                scope.$apply(function() {
                  if (modelCtrl) {
                    modelCtrl.$setViewValue(
                      result[options.display]
                        ? result[options.display]
                        : place.formatted_address,
                    )
                  } else {
                    element.val(
                      result[options.display]
                        ? result[options.display]
                        : place.formatted_address,
                    )
                  }
                  if (scope.gpCallback) {
                    scope.gpCallback({result: result, place: place})
                  }
                  if (modelCtrl) {
                    modelCtrl.$render()
                  }
                })
              }
            },
          )

          var enterKeydownListener = google.maps.event.addDomListener(
            element[0],
            'keydown',
            function(e) {
              if (e.keyCode === 13) {
                if (!options.submitOnEnter && itemSelected) {
                  e.preventDefault()
                  itemSelected = !itemSelected
                }
              }
            },
          )
          var enterKeyupListener = google.maps.event.addDomListener(
            element[0],
            'keyup',
            function(e) {
              if (e.keyCode === 38 || e.keyCode === 40) {
                itemSelected = angular
                  .element(document)
                  .find('.pac-item-selected').length
              }
            },
          )

          element.on('$destroy', function() {
            autocompleteListener.remove()
            enterKeydownListener.remove()
            enterKeyupListener.remove()
            autocomplete.unbindAll()
          })
        },
        post: function(scope, element, attributes, modelCtrl) {},
      },
    }
  }

  angular.module('routerApp').directive('gpGac', ['$rootScope', gpGac])
})()
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution lies in making the following changes to the Javascript file that controls the html, not the file that invokes the Google API.  Added the following line to the end of the gpSearchCb function in the correct javascript file:

```
$('#txtCity').focus()
```

and that maintains focus in the correct input field after making selection with a mouse.